# Is it possible to bind the visibility property of an element to an XML with WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have an XML containing lots of information, but there are some informations that isn't supposed to be shown unless it exists in the xml. I know I can do this manually, but it's not good.

imagine the xml something like this:

```
<root>
    <MandatoryContent />
    <OptionalContent />
</root>
```

I want to bind a button's visibility property to the existence of the OptionalContent element. Is it possible?

Comment: you can bind bool to visibility using a converter, if that's what you're asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bind directly to XML, but you can use something to create objects from XML.

LinqToXSD is a good candidate here.

It works like this: You create Xml Schema, LinqToXSD creates classes based on your schema, then you can read the XML and it will create the whole object tree based on your XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your element directly to the object it represents and then use a converter to set the visibility to `Visibility.Visible` when not null.

```
 <Label Visibility="{Binding MyObject, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}} />
```

Be sure to declare your converter in the ressources

```
<win:CustomWindow.Resources>
    <Converters:NullToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NullToVisibilityConverter" />
</win:CustomWindow.Resources>
```

And if you want a good example of converter, here is IValueConverter from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx